# UPDATE through selected radio button

Tags: php, radio-button

Hi guys and sorry for my english,

I try to make a simple UPDATE through selected radio buttons, but it's not working. I have a 3 <input type='radio'> buttons in while loop and every button should do something else which I want to filtered.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE state=0");
    while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        <form  method='post' action=''>
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='1' /> 1
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='2' /> 2
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='3' /> 3

         <input type='submit' value='Send' /> 
        </form>
    endwhile;
```

If I choose one of the three button and click on "Send", then one row (based on ID) should be UPDATE a MySQL db:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET state=(selected radio button number 1-3) WHERE id=$record[id]");
```

But, the script it must be out of the while loop and if I make it this way, it's not working because the script can't recognize which ID was chosen.

If I make it like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE state=0");
    while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        <form  method='post' action=''>
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='$record[id]' /> 1
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='$record[id]' /> 2
         <input type='radio' name='state' value='$record[id]' /> 3

         <input type='submit' value='Send' /> 
        </form>
    endwhile;
```

then ID is recognize by script, but I don't know, how can I filtered which number (1, 2 or 3) is sending to UPDATE query for "state" column. It's a big dilemma for me and I can't figure out. I need to recognized ID and filter the chosen number (1-3). Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

There is two options.

**First:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE state=0");
while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
    <form  method='post' action=''>
     <input type='hidden' name='recordId' value='$record[id]' />
     <input type='radio' name='state' value='1' />
     <input type='radio' name='state' value='2' />
     <input type='radio' name='state' value='3' />
     <input type='submit' value='Send' /> 
    </form>
endwhile;
```

and

```
$recordId = (int)$_POST['recordId'];
$state = (int)$_POST['state'];
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET state=$state WHERE id=$recordId");
```

**Second:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE state=0");
<form method='post' action=''>
    while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        <input type='radio' name='state[$record[id]]' value='1' />
        <input type='radio' name='state[$record[id]]' value='2' />
        <input type='radio' name='state[$record[id]]' value='3' />
    endwhile;
    <input type='submit' value='Send' /> 
</form>
```

and

```
foreach($_POST['state'] as $key => $val) {
    $recordId = (int)$key;
    $state = (int)$val;
    mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET state=$state WHERE id=$recordId");
}
```

(note that the code above is probably not syntactically correct, and given as an illustration to the idea)

Also, mixing up code and data is a bad practice; consider using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. $_POST['state'] contains the value of selected radio button only in the first example, but don't contains ID data.


I hear about <input type='hidden'> method, but I don't like it, because the radio buttons is in the loop. I try to make it different way.

Comment: Your original question does not contain any loops. What are you iterating over?

Comment: I wrote it, but I didn't consider it necessary to write it into the script, just a second, I make it right. EDIT: done, I hope it's ok now.

Comment: penartur: I really, really thank you very much. The first case is absolutely awesome and it's working like I need. Many thanks.